# open program and then hit f11 key

Tags: vbscript, autoit

i have the following cmd file that will open photo viewer and use c:\media for the pictures. Is there a way to have it hit f11 to run it automatically.

I have been trying to get it in vbs script to use sendkeys but unable to get the program to pull up. I am also open to autoit script Here is the cmd code. I know f11 runs it if i go to the window

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen c:\media
```

then i tried this

```
Sleep 1000

sendkeys "{F11}"
```

i could not get the vbscript to even open the program

if you create a folder and put in pictures on c:\media it should work

what am i doing wrong or how do i do this . I would give examples of the vbscript but nothing worked.

Comment: you need to give it an actual file, not just the folder: `... "c:\media\one-of-your-files.jpg"`. Besides that, your first code line works fine for me - on the `cmd` command line. Maybe [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-pictures/command-line-parameters-for-windows-picture-and/5eee98b5-107b-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) helps you to build a vbscript around it.

Comment: you can use the folder too. I just could not get the play button to work.

Comment: well that article did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") 
'oShell.Run "cmd /c ""%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe"" 

""%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll"" ""ImageView_Fullscreen"" ""c:\media"")"
Const iNormalFocus = 1
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "rundll32 " & chr(34) & "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" & chr(34) & ",ImageView_Fullscreen c:\media",iNormalFocus
Wscript.Sleep 1000
ObjShell.AppActivate("Windows Photo Viewer")

Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "{F11}"
```